# How to remove a time from a django DateTime query set?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am currently querying out Date Time data from my database in order to pass it into a chart.js function as labels.

This is the querying code:

```
sales_project_closing_date_data = Sales_project.objects.values_list('sales_project_closing_date').filter(sales_project_status = 'p4')
```

I am keen on only displaying the date and not the time , however i dont seem to be able to do it. 
Using the trunc function gives me the error :

```
Object of type TruncHour is not JSON serializable
```

In order to resolve that , I enveloped the object with another function to serialize it. Here is the error i got

```
'TruncHour' object is not iterable
```

Any form of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am passing the queryset into my template via restframework api and ajax

Comment: `not iterable` error usually means you forgot to add `.all()` to the model you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

If showing in html, you can use django `template_tag-{{ created|date:'Y-m-d' }}`
. Or you can  remove it by using a for-loop on the data and remove time in views like this

```
        for a in object_list:


            a['created'] = a['created'].strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

            a['modified'] = a['modified'].strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Hello Ann Kilzer , I have tried using this in my view but recieved a type error 'tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str'